# How do I override __getitem__ in a TypedDict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to make a `TypedDict` subclass that returns `None` if a key would cause a `KeyError` and that key is a part of the `TypedDict`'s annotations as `Optional`. I realize this isn't quite possible, since `TypedDict` can't be subclassed except to define annotations. Is there any other eloquent way to do this?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, get_args, get_origin

class FilledTypedDict(TypedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if k in self.__annotations__:
            annotation = self.__annotations__[k]
            if get_origin(annotation) is Union and type(None) in get_args(annotation):
                return None
        return super().__getitem__(k)
```

This gives me a `TypedDict classes can contain only type annotations`. How do I work my way around that?

Comment: Why not just call `get`? i.e. `d = {1: 2}; assert d.get(3) == None`

Comment: Even if you could create that class, it's not going to be useful. The ``TypedDict`` *represents* a "typed ``dict``", it is not a true separate type. Instantiating a ``TypedDict`` creates a ``dict``, and any ``dict`` with the correct keys can be assigned to a ``TypedDict`` variable.

Comment: Are you looking for a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: @flakes I'd still like it to `KeyError` when something that isn't in the `TypedDict`'s annotations is used as a key.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Almost. I didn't know that existed, but I'd like it to `KeyError` when something that isn't in the annotations is used. Edit - I realize that's possible with a `defaultdict`, but it wouldn't have the annotations like a TypedDict.

Comment: As far as I know, that is *not* the purpose of annotations. They are meant to make it easier to write code, not to handle types dynamically. So it sounds like your design is wrong, but I might be wrong...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Interesting, any literature on that? I could see libraries in the future taking advantage of typehints for Dependency Injection frameworks similar to the Java Guice library.

Comment: Using typehints at runtime is supported behaviour. See e.g. ``functools.singledispatch`` or ``dataclasses``, which both inspect annotations to adjust runtime behaviour. The problem with ``TypedDict`` are not the annotations, but it's own (lack of) class creation.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi do dataclasses actually use them at runtime or only when `TYPE_CHECKING == True`?

Comment: dataclasses [process the annotations at runtime](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17b16e13bb444001534ed6fccb459084596c8bcf/Lib/dataclasses.py#L926) to generate an actual class and its methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not. `TypedDict` is not a proper type, it is a *representation* of a regular `dict` with well-defined items.

The entire point is that there are no instances of `TypedDict` and any `dict` with correct items can be assigned to a `TypedDict` variable.

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class TD(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: str

print(type(TD(a=1, b="two")))  # <class 'dict'>

td: TD = {"a": 1, "b": "two"}  # valid
```

This makes it impossible to add behaviour to a `TypedDict`, since it must always match the `dict` behaviour exactly.

> [PEP 589 –– TypedDict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#class-based-syntax) - Methods are not allowed, since the runtime type of a TypedDict object will always be just `dict` (it is never a subclass of `dict`).

---

What can be done is to satisfy the "`TypedDict` with `Optional` values" type – by explicitly setting missing values to `None`.

```py
from typing import Optional, TypedDict

class Call(TypedDict):
    who: str
    when: Optional[str]

call: Call
call = Call(who="Gwen", when="tomorrow")  # valid
call = {"who": "me", "when": None}        # valid
call = {"who": "us"}                      # error: Missing key 'when' for TypedDict "Call"
```